# Get MIN() when using double GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join, min

I have this tricky situation with multiple JOINS and i am kinda stuck.Let me elaborate.

I have these tables:

RACES

```
id | system_id | track | race_name | race_date
----------------------------------------------
1  | 3         | Track1| Name      | 2016-10-07
2  | 5         | Track1| Name      | 2016-10-08
3  | 6         | Track1| Name      | 2016-10-09
```

RACERS

```
id | system_id | racer_name | gender | bday      | from | laps_completed
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 10002     | Name1      | 1      | 1996-10-07|Place | 14
2  | 10003     | Name2      | 0      | 1996-10-08|Place2| 33
3  | 10004     | Name3      | 1      | 1996-10-09|Place3| 44
```

RACERS_RACES

```
id | race_id | racer_id
-----------------------
1  | 3       | 10002 
2  | 5       | 10004
3  | 6       | 10003
```

LAPS

```
id | lap_time | system_id | racer_id
------------------------------------
1  | 25.33    | 1         | 10002
2  | 23.11    | 3         | 10003
3  | 28.55    | 7         | 10004
```

I have tried doing this query:

```
    SELECT r.system_id,MIN(l.lap_time) as fastest_lap,ra.racer_name,ra.racer_from,r.race_name,ra.laps_completed,r.race_date 
FROM races r 
LEFT JOIN racers_races rr ON r.system_id=rr.race_id 
LEFT JOIN racers ra ON rr.racer_id=ra.system_id 
LEFT JOIN laps l ON ra.system_id=l.racer_id 
WHERE l.lap_time!=0 
GROUP BY r.system_id,l.racer_id 
ORDER BY l.lap_time ASCenter code here
```

My problem is when i have multiple racers i have the same fastest lap for different races and it shouldnt be that way.It should return me the fastest lap of a racer on a certain race.

Here is an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1601/1) link.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MIN and the "double group by" isn't the problem.

It looks like you are missing a join condition. It looks like the join to `laps` should include matching to a specific `races`. I only see a join condition to a given `racers`.

If there was a `race_id` column in `laps`, then something like this:

```
  ...
  LEFT JOIN laps l 
         ON l.racer_id = ra.system_id
        AND l.race_id  = rr.race_id
  WHERE l.lap_time != 0
  ...
```

To me, it looks like we'd really want a join from `laps` to be to the `racers_races` table. The lap time isn't dependent on the racer... it depends on both the racer and the race... the racers participation in a race.

If there's no way to match a `laps` to a specific row in  `racers_races`, then there's a problem with the schema.

The other possibility (of course) is that the schema is correct. And the query is just going to return the fastest lap for a racer, so the query will return that same fastest time for a given `racers`, for each `races`.

---

Also note that the condition in the WHERE clause negates the outerness of the LEFT JOIN. If you really want that to be an "outer" join, then move that condition into the `ON` clause

```
  ...
  LEFT JOIN laps l 
         ON l.racer_id = ra.system_id
        AND l.<race_id> = rr.race_id
        AND l.lap_time != 0
  WHERE 1=1
  ...
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion,but it doesnt work.Maybe you got confused with system_id column.It is separated for each table,it is like a second primary id except on racers table there can be same system_id 's.

Comment: The original query has a join condition from `laps` to only `racer`, so a row from lap is going to match all races for that racer. Looks like we'd also need a condition that matches the `lap` to a specific `race_id`. (The only other column I saw in `laps` that looks like a foreign key is the `system_id` column... given the values 1, 3, 7 in the example data, it's not clear what column that is supposed to match in what other table. Maybe the schema needs a `race_id` column in `laps`? It looks to me like there should be a foreign key column in `laps` that references the `racers_races` table.)

Comment: Yep,you were right.I added the **race_id**  into the **laps** table and then referenced it on **racers_races** table and it is now working as it should have.I also had another mistake,the **laps_completed** should be in the **racers_races** table not in **racers**.Anyways,thanks a lot.